# Count the number of trues in a 2D subarray

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, binary-search

Given a 2D array of Boolean:

```java
{{false, false, true, false, true}
{true, false, true, false, false}
{false, true, false, false, false}
{false, false, false, false, false}
{true, true, true, true, true}}
```

**And you can't directly access the array, it must be through a ready-made method `hasTrue`** that takes in the start point and endpoint of subarray of the above 2D array and return a boolean if this subarray has at least 1 `true`.

```java
boolean hasTrue(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
```

For Example, if we want to check the area from index `(0,0)` to `(1,1)` we will call `hasTrue(0,0,1,1)` and it will return `true` since index `(1,0)` has the value `true`.
and we can give it the same endpoint as the start. for Example, `hasOnes(0,0,0,0)` this will check only a single index of the array which holds value `false` and will return `false`.

I need to implement a method that counts the number of the trues in a given subarray and I **must use `hasTrue` method**.

```java
int countTrues(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
```

One Solution is to brute force from the start index to the end and count the number of indices that have `true`. But in the best case complexity it will be `n*m`.

Another solution I am thinking of is to implement a recursive method that passes the whole subarray at once to `hasOnes()` and if the whole subarray returns `false` then I would not need to go through all the indices I will just return `0` which will be the best case `O(1)`.

If it returns `true` I will split the array and check every half, and continue to do so and count the number of trues.

How can I implement the second solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write C++ code (sorry) as forgot Java, but still can help you. Sure it won't be difficult to convert to Java. It implements your idea of recursively dividing into halfs, actually it divides into 4 almost-equal quadrants (sub-rectangles).

```
int countTrues(int xb, int yb, int xe, int ye) { // x/y begins/ends
    if (xb > xe || yb > ye) // zero-size (empty) array
        return 0;
    bool h = hasTrue(xb, yb, xe, ye);
    if (!h || (xb == xe && yb == ye)) // all-false or single-element array
        return (h ? 1 : 0);
    int xm = (xb + xe) / 2, ym = (yb + ye) / 2; // middle (center) point
    return ( // sum counts of 4 almost-equal quadrants (sub-rectangles)
        countTrues(xb, yb, xm, ym) +       // top-left
        countTrues(xm + 1, yb, xe, ym) +   // top-right
        countTrues(xb, ym + 1, xm, ye) +   // bottom-left
        countTrues(xm + 1, ym + 1, xe, ye) // bottom-right
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `countTrues` function can be implemented using recursion, basically you start by splitting the array in half horizontally, when there is no more than one row left, split it in half vertically, easy to understand:

```java
int countTrues(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    if (!hasTrue(startX, startY, endX, endY)) return 0;

    if (startX < endX) {
        //split horizontally
        return countTrues(startX, startY, (startX + endX) / 2, endY) +
                countTrues((startX + endX) / 2 + 1, startY, endX, endY);
    } else if (startY < endY) {
        //split vertically
        return countTrues(startX, startY, endX, (startY + endY) / 2) +
                countTrues(startX, (startY + endY) / 2 + 1, endX, endY);
    }

    //only one value left and is true
    return 1;
}
```

Here is a complete solution:

```java
public class Main {
    static boolean array[][] = {
            {false, false, true, false, true},
            {true, false, true, false, false},
            {false, true, false, false, false},
            {false, false, false, false, false},
            {true, true, true, true, true}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rowLen = array.length, colLen = array[0].length;

        int res = countTrues(0, 0, rowLen - 1, colLen - 1);

        System.out.println("number of Trues: " + res);
    }

    static boolean hasTrue(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
        while (startX <= endX) {
            int indexY = startY;
            while (indexY <= endY) {
                if (array[startX][indexY]) return true;
                indexY++;
            }
            startX++;
        }
        return false;
    }

    static int countTrues(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
        if (!hasTrue(startX, startY, endX, endY)) return 0;

        if (startX < endX) {
            //split horizontally
            return countTrues(startX, startY, (startX + endX) / 2, endY) +
                    countTrues((startX + endX) / 2 + 1, startY, endX, endY);
        } else if (startY < endY) {
            //split vertically
            return countTrues(startX, startY, endX, (startY + endY) / 2) +
                    countTrues(startX, (startY + endY) / 2 + 1, endX, endY);
        }

        //only one value left and is true
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem in the most efficient manner, we've to consider that when `hasTrue` returns true, we don't know how many `true` are present; however, when it returns false, we know that we can discard the whole area as its count (and that of any subarea) will always be 0. Therefore we should start with `hasTrue` on the largest area and if it returns true, then divide and continue; if it returns false, we can discard that whole area. A recursive implementation of this:

```
int countTrues(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
  int count = 0;
  if (endX >= startX && endY >= startY) {
    int midX = (endX + startX) / 2;
    int midY = (endY + startY) / 2;
    // top-left
    if (hasTrue(startX, startY, midX, midY)) {
      count += countTrues(startX, startY, midX, midY);
    }
    // top-right
    if (hasTrue(midX + 1, startY, endX, midY)) {
      count += countTrues(midX + 1, startY, endX, midY);
    }
    // bottom-left
    if (hasTrue(startX, midY + 1, midX, endY)) {
      count += countTrues(startX, midY + 1, midX, endY);
    }
    // bottom-right
    if (hasTrue(midX + 1, midY + 1, endX, endY)) {
      count += countTrues(midX + 1, midY + 1, endX, endY);
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

The important element in this implementation is that there is a recursive call to `countTrues` only when hasTrue returns true on the specific subarea. Without this, a recursive implementation is no better than the brute-force iterative implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Since *you can't directly access the array*, but only through a `hasTrue` method, you can build recursive `countTrues` method using *half division* approach. And you can use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) to iterate:

```java
static boolean[][] arr = {
        {false, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, false},
        {false, true, false, false, false},
        {false, false, false, false, false},
        {true, true, true, true, true}};
```

```java
static boolean hasTrue(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    // invalid syntax
    if (startX > endX || startY > endY)
        return false;

    return IntStream
            // iterate over specified
            // range of the rows
            .rangeClosed(startX, endX)
            // get row by index
            // Stream<boolean[]>
            .mapToObj(i -> arr[i])
            // at least one true in any row
            .anyMatch(row -> IntStream
                    // iterate over specified
                    // range of the elements
                    .rangeClosed(startY, endY)
                    // at least one true in the row
                    .anyMatch(j -> row[j]));
}
```

```java
static int countTrues(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    // no trues on this iteration
    if (!hasTrue(startX, startY, endX, endY))
        return 0;

    // recursive calls
    int lengthX = endX - startX;
    int lengthY = endY - startY;
    int middleX = lengthX / 2;
    int middleY = lengthY / 2;
    if (lengthX > 0 || lengthY > 0)
        return IntStream
                // if 'lengthX > 0' then two iterations X:
                // from beginning to middle and from
                // middle to end, otherwise one iteration
                .rangeClosed(0, lengthX > 0 ? 1 : 0)
                .map(i -> i == 0 ? 0 : middleX + 1)
                .map(i -> IntStream
                        // if 'lengthY > 0' then two iterations Y:
                        // from beginning to middle and from
                        // middle to end, otherwise one iteration
                        .rangeClosed(0, lengthY > 0 ? 1 : 0)
                        .map(j -> j == 0 ? 0 : middleY + 1)
                        // recursive calls, if it is necessary for
                        // top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right
                        .map(j -> countTrues(startX + i, startY + j,
                                i == 0 ? startX + middleX : endX,
                                j == 0 ? startY + middleY : endY))
                        .sum())
                .sum();

    // if it reached this point, this point is true
    return 1;
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(hasTrue(1, 1, 3, 3)); // true
    System.out.println(countTrues(1, 1, 3, 3)); // 2
}
```